# Is there any way to return the color of a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing

For example if you set the color of a textfield as `Color.RED`, is there a method to actually return that color?

I found a method in the Oracle logs called `getCaretColor()` but it doesn't seem to return the right thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JTextField inherits `getBackground()` and `getForeground()` from Component. If I understand your question, that should get you the values.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will return a JTextField with a black background and red text.

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java"); // Just the window title, name doesn't matter
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        Color color = new Color(255,0,0); // Set the text color

        textField.setBackground(Color.BLACK); // Set the black background

        textField.setForeground(color);
        frame.add(textField);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```